# Get magic number from git packfile index in Haskell

Tags: git, haskell, bytestring

I'm wanting to get the magic number from a git packfile index to ensure that it is indeed a packfile. The [pack format documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/pack-format.txt) states that the magic number is "/377tOc". When I open the packfile with Ruby for example, I get this back when reading the file:

```
> File.open("pack-4412d2306cfe9a0b6d1b9b4430abc767022e8a3c.idx").read(4)
=> "\377tOc"
```

But in Haskell I get this:

```
> h <- openFile "pack-4412d2306cfe9a0b6d1b9b4430abc767022e8a3c.idx" ReadMode
> Data.ByteString.hGet h 4
=> "\255tOc"
```

I take it I'm missing something obvious, but it's not clear to me what that is. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The non-ascii character ('\255') is just being shown in decimal, not octal.

Confirming, according to `od` the first 4 bytes are indeed, in octal/ascii or 1 byte decimal:

```
> $ od -c foo.idx  | head -1
0000000 377   t   O   c  \0  \0  \0 002  \0  \0 002 250  \0  \0 005   B

> $ od -t u1 /tmp/x | head -1
0000000 255 116  79  99   0   0   0   2   0   0   2 168   0   0   5  66
```

And in Haskell:

```
> s <- Data.ByteString.readFile "foo.idx"
> Data.ByteString.take 4 s
"\255tOc"
```

So, just remember that 255 in decimal is 377 in octal.

Comment: Thanks Don, that's just what I needed to hear. What confused me is that I thought the \ indicated it was octal. Some Googling turned up http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/characters-strings-and-escaping-rules.html#id690711 which indicates that octal numbers are preceeded with an oh, so \o377 == \255. This addendum is for the benefit of others, since you obviously know all this :)